# Best practice to hide a service implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to hide the implementation (concrete class) of a service (interface) from the API user. The implementation is provided to the user by a factory which uses the Java API *ServiceLoader* mechanism. This Loader requires the implementation class to have public visibility. This is OK as long as the implementation is hidden in a different JAR (apart from the API JAR) the user is not directly depending on.

However, for easy distribution the content of the JAR with the default implementation is packed into the API JAR. So effectively the user depends on this prepacked JAR where the default implementation class is available with public visibility. Nothing keeps people from directly instantiating the implementation. I don't want that to be possible.

My bad ideas:

- implement an own version of ServiceLoader which allows to load package private implementations (btw, why does the Java API ServiceLoader doesn't allow this?)
- ship separate API and implementation JARs

What do you think is the right way? Any compromise?

Using OSGi or other heavy machinery is out of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disappointing maybe but:

- Make a separate jar and put that with the other third party jars.
- Let the installer/the deployment process handle nice packaging of all.
- Do not make this jar available during compile time; maven: `<scope>runtime</scope>`.

The only other way would be the have `@Deprecated` in the javadoc, with as comment how to use the corresponding class using the java service API.

Comment: hmm this is what I expected. Maybe give away a POM template with the library might be it. But isn't the package private ServiceLoader also a valid way? Is there a specific reason for you to sort that approach out? Thank you.

Comment: No, package private should do too. Just that most often some of the (low-level) classes must be public.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can create an internal interface that is visible only to relevant friend assemblies, and then explicitly implement the interface. I'm not sure how you would do this in Java, but conceptually this is how I've been able to work around this problem in the .NET world.

**EDIT** I just looked it up, from what I can tell Java doesn't have explicit implementation for interfaces. As an FYI, an explicit implementation of an interface requires you to make a function call through an interface member, you can't call it as a member of the implementing class. This is why my technique works for me, at least in the .NET world.

Alternatively, I would suggest putting the interface in another JAR, and don't distribute it with the API

Comment: Really interesting approach from a completely different view. Thanks for sharing, although it doesn't work for Java.

Comment: Well I was hoping there might be some mechanism in Java to do it this way, but unfortunately that isn't the case. It's been too long since I've worked with Java, so I don't remember little details that might help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily prevent people from instantiating/accessing any shipped class.

As such I would perhaps simply wrap the `ServiceLoader` mechanism that you're using and provide the instantiated class referenced through a Java interface (rather than as a concrete implementation reference).

Comment: OK *hide* is probably the wrong word. With reflection you can do all the dirty tricks, I know. Of course the API is referencing only the interface not the implementation. But I don't want that people can instantiate the implementation by accident (e.g. using code completion)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer your first approach, making the implementation class package private, and using a ServiceLoctor to retrieve a specific service. In my project, the package structure is like this:

```
-package
   |-ServiceInterface(public)
   |-ServiceImplementation(default,package private)
   |-ServiceLocator(public)
```

The serviceLocator is like this:

```
public class ServiceLocator{
    private static final Map<String,Service> services;

    static {
         services=new HashMap<String,Service>();
         services.put("default",new ServiceImplementation());//hide implementation
    }
    public Service getService(String name){
         return services.get(name);
    } 

    public registerService(Service service, String name){
         services.put(name,service)
    }
}
```

The end user does not have access to the implementation class, and in later time, you can easily change to use a different implementation class.

Comment: sadly this doesn't work for me, because the service implementations might be bundled by a third party. The service is a SPI which is implemented by other developers, but their code can't run until my code knows the other code. So nobody can invoke registerService(). This is why I use a ServiceLoader.